# select values matching value from other column in the same table

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I need help writing a query. What I'm trying to do, is to check, if any category_id have both (or even more) given tag_id's. I'm looking for most optimal query...

if any category_id have both (or even more) tag_id's

```
id              int(10) NO  PRI     auto_increment
client_id       int(10) YES         
category_id     int(10) YES         
tag_id          int(10) YES
```

sample data:

```
41  1   137 183
40  1   137 124
39  1   136 179
38  1   136 124
62  1   143 263
61  1   143 200
60  1   143 135
59  1   143 131
58  1   143 125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT category_id
FROM Mytable
WHERE tag_id IN(183, 200)
GROUP BY category_id
HAVING COUNT(Distinct tag_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The value tested in the HAVING clause should be equal to the number of elements in the IN clause.

```
SELECT category_id
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE tag_id IN (124, 183)
    GROUP BY category_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2;
```